# this loop will not execute the code after it

Tags: python-3.x

I am super stumped. my code does what I want it to, but after that, it just dies. I have made sure that it is not an infinite loop but it still manages to stop. my code is very unorganized so I'm just going to provide a snippet, if you need the whole thing I can give it. thanks in advance!

```
def matrixVisualizer1():
    global dim1, m2, matrix1
    i = 0
    rows = []
    i2 = 0
    i3 = 0
    while i <= dim1: #here
        while i2 < int(m2):
            if i3 < dim1:
                rows.insert(i2, matrix1[i3])
                i2 += 1
                i3 += 1
        if i2 >= int(m2):
            print(rows)
            rows = []
            i2 = 0
        i += 1
matrixVisualizer1()
print("hello") # <-----wont print this
```

Comment: please explain with more details, exactly what you want to do ?

Comment: well it does what I want it to, but it won't run anything after(like the help at the bottom), I thought it might be a repeating number but I tested them all and they all end.

Comment: I got it! I found a site for debugging and it helped a lot. I'm sorry I wasn't able to provide enough info, I know it was really vague

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. I took some test values for your global variables, please tell me if they aren't what you were originally giving them.

```
dim1 = 9
matrix1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
m2 = 3.5
def matrixVisualizer1():
    global dim1, m2, matrix1
    i = 0
    rows = []
    i2 = 0
    i3 = 0
    while i < int(m2): #changed here
        while i2 < int(m2):
            if i3 < dim1:
                rows.insert(i2, matrix1[i3])
                i2 += 1
                i3 += 1
        if i2 >= int(m2):
            print(rows)
            rows = []
            i2 = 0
        i += 1
matrixVisualizer1()
print("hello") # <-----will print this now
```

You would want to change the condition in the outer while to `int(m2)`

If you loop it more than 3 (here) times, then the `if` condition in the inner while evaluates to `false` because `i3` is already looped to its maximum value.
This does not let `i2` to increment and causes an infinite loop.

I hope it answers the question.